# Using Javascript, how do I compare 2 values to see if they are divisible by each other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, html

I am trying to write a event handler here so that when users enter a number in the first text box and the second text box, and click "Compare Values" button, a function executes and it checks

if either of the number is ZERO, it prints out on "box5", "You have entered zero"

if the two numbers are the same, it prints out on "box5", "The numbers are the same"

If the first number is evenly divisible by the second, it prints out on "box5", "The first is divisible by the second"

if the second number is evenly divisible by the first, it prints out on "box5", "The second is divisible by the first"

else-if the numbers do not divide into each other, it prints out on "box5", "They are not divisible"

I've already created the HTML page for this but I do not know how I should approach this. A few users have told me to use the "keyup" method and I was hoping if someone could show me an example of the way they would approach this using the "keyup" method if that is possible. Thanks in advance

```
<p> Enter two numbers and we will tell you if they are evenly divisble
<p> Enter your first number:</p> <input type="text" id="box3">
<p> Enter your second number: </p> <input type="text" id="box4"> 
<button id="compareValue">Compare Values</button>
<p> Output will appear here: </p> <input text="type" id="box5" disabled>
```

I am just trying to create a simple tool to compare 2 numbers entered by a user, and check to see if they are divisible, and if they are, which number is divisible by which one, and to make sure that no ZERO is entered in the input, and else-if nothing is divisible by each other, then it tells you they are not divisible.

EDIT: I forgot to include my JavaScript attempt:

```
let firstNumber = document.getElementById("box3")
let secondNumber = document.getElementById("box4")
let outputNumber = document.getElementById("box5")

$(document).ready(function(){
$("compareValue").keyup(function(){
let a = firstNumber.value;
let b = secondNumber.value;
  if (a === 0 || b === 0);
    let outputNumber.value = "The Number is ZERO."
  });
  if (a % b );
    let outputNumber.value = "First number is divisible by the second number."
  });
  if (b % a);
    let outputNumber.value = "Second Number is divisble by the first number."
  });
  else-if (a !== b && b !== a);
    let outputNumber.value = "The numbers are not divisible."
  });
});
```

Comment: I suspect you'll want to look at and use `switch()` statement.

Comment: I forgot to include my attempted javascript. I had edited my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `%` (modulus) for divisibility, and `==` for testing equality:

```js
function compare() {
  var value1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("box3").value);
  var value2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("box4").value);
  var display = document.getElementById("box5");
  if (value1 == 0 || value2 == 0) {
    display.value = "You have entered zero";
  } else if (value1 == value2) {
    display.value = "The numbers are the same";
  } else if (value1 % value2 == 0) {
    display.value = "The first is divisible by the second";
  } else if (value2 % value1 == 0) {
    display.value = "The second is divisible by the first";
  } else {
    display.value = "They are not divisible";
  }
}
```

```html
<p> Enter two numbers and we will tell you if they are evenly divisble</p>
<p> Enter your first number:</p> <input type="text" id="box3">
<p> Enter your second number: </p> <input type="text" id="box4">
<button id="compareValue" onclick="compare()">Compare Values</button>
<p> Output will appear here: </p> <input text="type" id="box5" disabled>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you tagged this with `jquery` I am guessing you would be open to a jQuery solution.

```js
$(function() {
  function compare(a, b) {
    if (typeof a !== "number" || typeof b !== "number") {
      return false;
    }
    var result;
    switch (true) {
      case (a === 0 || b === 0):
        result = "You have entered zero";
        break;
      case (a === b):
        result = "The numbers are the same";
        break;
      case (a % b === 0):
        result = "The first is divisible by the second";
        break;
      case (b % a === 0):
        result = "The second is divisible by the first";
        break;
      default:
        result = "They are not divisible";
        break;
    }
    return result;
  }
  $("#compareValue").click(function(e) {
    var v1 = parseInt($("#box3").val());
    var v2 = parseInt($("#box4").val());
    $("#box5").val(compare(v1, v2));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Enter two numbers and we will tell you if they are evenly divisble
  <p> Enter your first number:</p> <input type="text" id="box3">
  <p> Enter your second number: </p> <input type="text" id="box4">
  <button id="compareValue">Compare Values</button>
  <p> Output will appear here: </p> <input text="type" id="box5" disabled>
```

Enjoy!

Comment: thanks. i have made 2 versions of this, one using strictly Javascript and the other using jQuery!

Comment: @MichaelKheong as you can see, the `compare()` I wrote can be used either way. As long as you provide 2 numbers, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're really new to this whole html/js thing; so excuse me if I'm making this explanation very very explicit.

1. Add a `script` tag after your html, e.g. `<script> stuff here </script>`
2. Replace the stuff here with some javascript code.

To get a variable reference to an element, use

`var someElement = document.getElementById("#id_of_an_element")`

To get or set the value of the data inside an input element: use

`inputElement.value`

To handle a click event on an element: use

```
buttonElement.addEventListener("click", function(){
    //Do stuff!
})
```

And you should be good to go from there.

Good luck getting on your feet! To be fair to all parties, this is a very very n00b level query for stackoverflow and nothing that can't be answered by following a 30 minute guide on youtube, so take some initiative - it really helps :)

Comment: I had forgot to include my attempted javascript. I have updated it